# How can I play a youtube video in swfloader?

Tags: apache-flex, video, air, youtube

I embed a youtube video in my air application. It loaded and played well, but I cannot play more than one video at the time, only one video is played at the time, do you know why?
The code is:

```
url:String = "http://in.youtube.com/v/fVGk5qm6Mac&hl=en&fs=1";    
             //texturl.text=url;
            swfloader.load(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I guess that if you create separate SWFLoader instances for each video you want to play, it shouldn't be a problem. It's hard to tell from the code you provide if you are using 1 or more SWFLoader objects.

Comment: in my application i want to play the videos from youtube website with  youtubeapi and play using that code how can do that..can u help me on this............url:String="http://in.youtube.com/v/"+youtubevideoid+"&hl=en&fs=1";swfloader.load(url)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this, but like Christophe mentioned, you'd need one SWFLoader instance for each video that you want to display at the same time. If you want to play the videos one after the other, you could use the same SWFLoader to do that though. Just wait until the video finishes playing, and then load the new one at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

[Sample Youtube to Flex App](http://www.brentlamborn.com/examples/Flex_youtube/srcview/index.html)